# Configure postfix virtual transport to deliver mail to arbitrary (local) addresses

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm using Postfix in a very niche application with no inbound or outbound SMTP connectivity (other than via the loopback interface).

I would like to configure the postfix `virtual` transport to deliver mail to local files for arbitrary addresses matching a specific pattern. That is, assuming that the final transport is `virtual`, I would like mail to `foo0` to get delivered to `/var/vmail/foo0`, mail for `foo100` to go to `/var/vmail/foo100`, etc. The files should all be owned by the same uid/gid, managed via static `virtual_uid_maps` and `virtual_gid_maps`.

The catch is that the specific target addresses aren't known in advance.

What I *really* want is something like:

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
```

With `vmailbox` containing something like:

```
/^(foo[0-9]*)(@.*)?/ ${1}
```

But the `virtual` transport explicitly does not support regular expression substitution...nor does it support the `socketmap` table type, which would be another way of solving this particular issue.

I guess I could solve this with a custom transport, but I was hoping to not write an MDA.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

With a little additional research, this turned out to be easier than I thought.

In `main.cf`:

```
mydestination = localhost

# leave valid recipient checking up to the mda
local_recipient_maps =

# don't permit any outbound mail
default_transport = error:No outbound mail delivery!

# look up transport via transport map
transport_maps = lmdb:transport
```

In `transport`:

```
# deliver root locally
root@localhost  local:localhost

# deliver everything else via our fakemail transport
*               fakemail:
```

In `master.cf`:

```
fakemail unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=DBFRXhu directory=/var/spool/vmail user=fakemail:fakemail
        argv=/usr/local/bin/fakemail ${user}
```

And in `fakemail`:

```
#!/bin/sh

umask 007
cat >> "$1"
```

With the above configuration, `echo test message | mail -s test root` goes to `/var/mail/root`. Any other unqualified address gets delivered via the `fakemail` script to `/var/spool/vmail/<user>`. E.g.:

```
# echo test message | mail -s test1 user001
# echo test message | mail -s test2 user001
# mail -f /var/spool/vmail/user001
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/vmail/user001": 2 messages 2 new
>N  1 root@localhost     Sat Nov 11 20:40   16/482   test1
 N  2 root@localhost     Sat Nov 11 20:40   16/482   test2
```

We could obviously replace the `fakemail` script with something more robust, perhaps implementing some simple pattern matching there, etc.